# How to delete GridView's first row

Tags: c#, gridview, datatable, row, delete-row

I have a gridview which is populated when 2 buttons are pressed.

```
                <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"
                    ShowFooter="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Width="100%" Height="100%" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#3F51B5" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White" BorderWidth="1px">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="RowNumber" HeaderText="Nr.">
                            <ControlStyle BorderStyle="None" />
                        </asp:BoundField>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Message" HeaderText="Message">
                            <ControlStyle BorderStyle="None" />
                        </asp:BoundField>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Data" HeaderText="Data">
                            <ControlStyle BorderStyle="None" />
                        </asp:BoundField>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="ClasaMesaj" HeaderText="ClasaMesaj">
                            <ControlStyle BorderStyle="None" />
                        </asp:BoundField>
                    </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>
```

With `FirstGridViewRow()` function, I create `GridView1` with a new row. `FirstGridViewRow()` is called in `PageLoad`

```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.IsPostBack)
            return;
        FirstGridViewRow();
    }

    private void FirstGridViewRow()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        DataRow dr = null;
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("RowNumber", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Message", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Data", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("ClasaMesaj", typeof(string)));

        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["RowNumber"] = 1;
        dr["Message"] = "";// string.Empty;
        dr["Data"] = "";// string.Empty;
        dr["ClasaMesaj"] = 0;

        dt.Rows.Add(dr);

        //   dt.Rows.Remove(dt.Rows[0]); //I have tried like this, but no row would be added

        ViewState["CurrentTable"] = dt;
        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
```

Clicking one of the two buttons, I add each time a new row.

```
           private void AddNewRow(string s, string s1, int ClasaMesaj)
    {
        int rowIndex = 1;
        DataTable dtCurrentTable = (DataTable)ViewState["CurrentTable"];
        DataRow drCurrentRow = dtCurrentTable.NewRow(); // null;// dtCurrentTable.NewRow();

        for (int i = 1; i <= dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            drCurrentRow["RowNumber"] = i+1;
            drCurrentRow[1] = s;// "s";
            drCurrentRow[2] = s1;// "s1";
            drCurrentRow[3] = ClasaMesaj;
            rowIndex++;
        }
        dtCurrentTable.Rows.Add(drCurrentRow);
        ViewState["CurrentTable"] = dtCurrentTable;
        GridView1.DataSource = dtCurrentTable;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        clsMsg = 1;
        DateTime data = DateTime.Now;
        string dt = data.ToString();
        AddNewRow("Start", dt, clsMsg);
    }

    protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        clsMsg = 2; 
        DateTime data = DateTime.Now;
        string dt = data.ToString();
        AddNewRow("Stop", dt, clsMsg);
    }
```

So when page is loaded, the `GridView1` has 1 row (the one initialized in `FirstGridViewRow()`). When I press one of the buttons, row 2 is created. I would like either to delete the row initialized or to populate it with info when button is pressed. How could I do this?  I tried to get rid of `FirstGridViewRow()` and to use just `AddNewRow()`, but with no success.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I've added a delete first row in your code for you.

```
static bool first = true;
       private void AddNewRow(string s, string s1, int ClasaMesaj)
{
    int rowIndex = 1;
    DataTable dtCurrentTable = (DataTable)ViewState["CurrentTable"];
    DataRow drCurrentRow = dtCurrentTable.NewRow(); // null;// 
 dtCurrentTable.NewRow();

    for (int i = 1; i <= dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        drCurrentRow["RowNumber"] = i+1;
        drCurrentRow[1] = s;// "s";
        drCurrentRow[2] = s1;// "s1";
        drCurrentRow[3] = ClasaMesaj;
        rowIndex++;
    }
    dtCurrentTable.Rows.Add(drCurrentRow);
    ViewState["CurrentTable"] = dtCurrentTable;




if (first == true){
dtCurrentTable.Rows.RemoveAt(0);
first = false;
}



    GridView1.DataSource = dtCurrentTable;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Just a question though. does the first row only need to be deleted the first time the button is pressed or every time?

Comment: Many thanks, Random Stuff! Just the first time the button is pressed. I will test your code as soon as possible. :)

Comment: Your welcome, let me know how you go.
I updated to only delete the first row on the first press